# Flow treats imported types as any

Tags: javascript, flowtype, static-analysis

I have a type def files something like this:

```
// Type Definitions
export interface IPane {
  key: string;
  tab?: string;
  closable?: boolean;
  title?: string;
}


export interface ApolloGraphQLResult<T> {
  data: T;
  errors: Array<any>;
  loading: boolean;
  networkStatus: NetworkStatus;
  stale: boolean;
}
```

However when I import those types, Flow just treat as any types:

```
import type { IPane } from '../../types'; // [Flow] IPane: any
```

Here's my flowconfig settings.

```
[ignore]
.*/dist/.*
.*/node_modules/jsonlint/.*
.*/node_modules/rc-util/.*

[include]

[libs]
./src/global.js
flow-typed

[options]
esproposal.decorators=ignore
module.name_mapper='^.*\.css$' -> 'css-module-flow'
module.name_mapper='^.*\.scss$' -> 'css-module-flow'
module.name_mapper='^.*\.less$' -> 'css-module-flow'
module.name_mapper='^components\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/components/\1'
module.name_mapper='^containers\(.*\)$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/src/containers/\1'
module.system=haste
module.system.node.resolve_dirname=node_modules

[lints]
```

It seems nothing wrong with my settings. Restarting flow doesn't changed anything.

What am I missing? Why Flow treating types as any?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `export type` instead of `export interface`?

Comment: Yes, it's same.